# Can not authorize a FB application on IE9

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

When testing a FB app I created, I was able to authorize the app on all browsers but IE9 where the browser displays the attached screen  again when clicking 'Go To App' button.

I am using PHP FB SDK, the latest version.

Tested in FF and Chrome and is working, any ideas?

**Edit**:
It seems a bug with FB:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/434269633305911?browse=search_50acc066047f50931832838

Comment: if you post some of your code I'm sure someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a bug with FB and was resolved this morning.

Answer (score 1):

This is JavaScript problem. Use authorization without js. Authorization in server-side the best because is independent of the browser.